Role of the exposed gate for some SSR types
Sharp's PR36MF21NSZH (also Panasonic's AQH1213), which is “It (RMS) ≤0.6 A, Zero Cross type, DIP 8pin, Triac output SSR”, has an exposed gate connected to the zero-cross circuitry. What is the role of this gate, and should it be treated in some way when using a small switching AC-DC regulator as the load of the SSR?


Datasheet here, also, for AQH1213.

From the datasheet:  Note: Connection of an external resister, etc.,
to terminal No. 5 (gate) is not necessary.

"From the datasheet: Note: Connection of an external resister, etc., to terminal No. 5 (gate) is not necessary."- thank you for your answer. Well, that note, in itself, is very puzzling. An external resistor connected to what? To air? As I see it, that exposed "gate", which connects to the zero-cross detector, can be used to block the detector, block the switching of the whole ssr on or, maybe, turn the whole SSR into a non-zero-cross type.  That functional diagram (first picture) doesn't really tell me too much about the internal schematics and I thought maybe someone knows more.

Could they need the DIP8 surface area for thermal (0.6A is a lot)? If so, there's not a lot of downsides for breaking out empty pin slots, and the gate could be handy to monitor for timing, verifying AC is actually flowing, or as you say, adjusting the operation. A lot of open-collector optos break out the base (fed by the LED), so it could be tradition.

600mA is not that much for an SSR, and the gate is not the best structural detail to draw the built-up heat. It could be an input but I think we should agree that the datasheet is kind of... datashit. Any input should be documented. For my part, I'm just not comfortable with a terminal named "gate" floating around, especially around high electric fields.
